# Optional Lists and following mapping

Tags: java, performance, list, lambda, option-type

I hope you're well.

I have encountered some scenarios that involves list manipulations. The expectation would be to do the following data mapping of that list and avoid any NPE. This would be done with a for loop and inside querying for any data, that could contain another list, and so on. What would be the best approach of manipulating the data, taking in account the performance. Would it be better to maintain the for loop or could we improve with optionals and lambda, or at least match the same performance?
For example:

```
class MyObject {
    //Constructors
    private int id;
    private List<MySecondObject> objList;
    private String data;
    //getters, setters
}
class MySecondObject {
    //Constructors
    private int id;
    private String desc;
    //getters, setters
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<MyObject> objList = getList();
        List<String> descList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(objList == null){
            return;
        }
        for(MyObject o : objList) {
            if(o.getData() == null || o.getData().isEmpty()){
                continue;
            }
            if(o.getObjList() != null) {
                for(MySecondObject s : o.getObjList()) {
                    if(s.getDesc() != null && !s.getDesc().isEmpty()) {
                        descList.add(s.getDesc());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Have a nice day.

Comment: Why are you `break`ing under `if(o.getObjList() == null)`? Didn't you mean to `continue`?

Comment: I have edited the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you do in your code, but using *Streams*:

```
public static List<String> createDescList(List<MyObject> objList) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(objList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .filter(obj -> isNotEmpty(obj.getData()))
                   .map(MyObject::getObjList)
                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .filter(obj -> isNotEmpty(obj.getDesc()))
                   .map(MySecondObject::getDesc)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// TODO can be replaced with org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotEmpty() or isNotBlank()
private static boolean isNotEmpty(String str) {
    return str != null && !str.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Yes, expect `break` statement in the middle. It seems that this is typo

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Thanks for your response. So, could you please be verbose about the performance implications. Also, is this the best approach of checking the nulls? Can we inherit in the filters and mappings the Optional? Sorry if this is a silly question. Thanks!

Comment: I am old school boy. So if I am really worry about performance, I do it without Streams, because I am not sure about internal implementation. But 99% of time I use this way.

Comment: I think, I would go for parallelStream in this case.